# Regular expression matching multiple entries, spanning multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm fairly new to regular expressions and what I'm trying to achieve seems impossible after a few hours of trying. I could not find similar issues, so that is why I am making a separate question; please excuse me if there is already a question like that.

Now. I want to match every occurrence of the regular expression throughout the document; the occurrences are spanning multiple lines. Here is an example:

```
// javascript.js

/**
 * #start?
 * @name myFunction(p1)
 * @desc Description of the function
 * @param p1 : int = Parameter of type int
 * ...
 * #end?
 */
function myFunction(p1) { ... }

/**
 * #start?
 * @name yourFunction()
 * @desc Description of the function
 * ...
 * #end?
 */
function yourFunction() { ... }
```

With the regular expression I would like to match the comment sections that describe the functions, from `#start?` to `#end?`. As a result I want to have 2 matched occurrences - the description of the first function and that of the second one.

What I came with is `(#start\?)[\s\S]+(#end\?)`, but as you can guess it matches the first `#start?` and closes the match with the **second** `#end?`

How can I make it match all similar comment sections as separate occurrences?

**Thank you very much for your time!**

**Update/Solution**
As pointed out by **Wiktor Stribiżew** - **lazy != greedy** The working regular expression for this case is `(#start\?)[\s\S]+?(#end\?)`

Comment: have you tried the 'g' flag? Here's an article on it. http://2ality.com/2013/08/regexp-g.html

Comment: @PerrinPrograms Yes I did. I am using regex101.com to test my regex; tried all the flags available to no avail.

Comment: have you written any code yet for it ? Or just used regex101 for testing?

Comment: Lazy !=greedy. `#start\?[\s\S]+?#end\?`

Comment: I just realized I read the question wrong. I thought you were only getting the first occurrence of that pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew And I didn't think to search for "... matching too much..." Thank you very much, it's perfect now!